# GIT can't pull: failed to symlink 'path/filename': File name too long

Tags: macos, git, pull

Feeling silly, but I can't figure out what to do here.

I have a local copy of a repository stored on a remote server. The remote server has changes I need, and I've committed changes on my local copy. I can't push, because I need to merge the changes from the newer version that exists on the server. When I pull, I get this error:

```
 git pull origin master
 From server.name:reponame
  * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 fatal: failed to symlink 'path/to/filename ': File name too long
```

Not sure what would be happening here. The crazy thing is that the file `path/to/filename` is an actual file, not a symlink. Further, `path/to/filename` isn't even the longest path.

Really confused as to where to start debugging this problem.

Comment: `ls -la path/to`? Maybe something is funky with the file?

Comment: Try to use "git fetch origin" and then "git rebase origin/master"

Comment: I presume `path.to/filename`,or `path/to/filename` isn't the actual path. It might help if you show us the actual path. Are *any* directories in the path symlinks?

Comment: @nneonneo —things appear to be normal. @Keith-Thompson —you're right, that's not the actual path. None of the directories on the path are symlinks, though the the `to` portion is actually a dotfolder: `.libs`.

Answer (score 0):

The only place where I see a failed to symlink is in the [merge-recursive.c file](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/merge-recursive.c#L776-L783):

```
if (S_ISLNK(mode)) {
  char *lnk = xmemdupz(buf, size);
  safe_create_leading_directories_const(path);
  unlink(path);
  if (symlink(lnk, path))
    die_errno(_("failed to symlink '%s'"), path);
  free(lnk);
}
```

It looks like the remote repo you are pulling from contains `filename` as a symlink, while your local repo contains the same `filename` as a plain file.
That could be the cause of the fatal error message.

Comment: That's entirely possible, though I'm not sure how to debug the issue because the file started off on my system as a file. A colleague has been working on the same project and his repo is on a FAT drive, I think, but everything shows up as normal on his machine, and he's the last one that pushed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start debugging by beginning with `git fetch` and only after that succeeds, go for `git merge`.  Presumably (as @VonC noted) the error will only happen with `git merge` (which makes sense since pull is just fetch-then-merge here).  Since the `fetch` will have succeeded, you can inspect the commit(s) that cause the failing merge, and perhaps run the whole thing under `strace` or similar to observe the failing system call.

(The split into fetch+merge is not required, you can strace a pull, it's just that it should help reduce the amount of irrelevant crud to comb through.)

[Edit: and, once again SO has resurrected an old question... gotta start looking at the timestamps on these!  And, noting the OSX tag, make that `dtruss` instead of strace.]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but in my case I hadn't time to check how it would be happen. I resolved it by use command below - may be will be helpful for someone:

```
git config core.symlinks false
```

However, I don't know how this works for whole project, so you can use it for only your responsibility.